# Куда делать память после удаления указателя?

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть бинарное дерево. Каждый узел в нем - это такая структура:

```
struct TNode {
    int memory;
    TNode* left;
    TNode* right;
};
```

Инициализируется узел вот так:

```
Node* node = new Node;
node->memory = value;
node->left = NULL;
node->right = NULL;
```

То есть это число и два указателя на другие структуры-узлы. Отсюда у меня вопрос. Если я удалю узел оператором delete, то что будет с памятью, которую я выделил при инициализации оператором new? Указатель удалится, но будет ли дальше занимать место та память, которую я выделил через new? Или она автоматически станет "свободной", поскольку больше указателей на нее нет?

Comment: Наоборот, с указателем ничего не произойдет, а объект, на который тот указывает будет разрушен и память, им занимаемая, освобождена. Причем после этого указатель по-прежнему будет указывать на тот же, теперь уже не существующий, объект.

Comment: И что тогда делать с указателем? Он же занимает память, верно? Или он удалится после выхода из области видимости, как обычная переменная?

Comment: Указатель - это и есть обычная переменная. Точнее обычный тип данных, который может использоваться при объявлении переменных. В вашем примере `node` - самая обычная переменная с автоматическим временем хранения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове оператора `delete` / `delete[]`, с указателем ничего не происходит, т.е. если в нем был какой-то адрес, то он таким же и останется, если его не затереть вручную.

Т.е. например не присвоить `NULL`:

```
Node * pNode = new Node;
...
delete pNode;
pNode = NULL; // or nulltpr;
```

Но при этом **важно понимать**, что адрес на который он указывает — **инвалидный**.

Т.е. адрес памяти теперь вами больше не может использоваться, и если вы будете дальше его использовать, то либо вы получите [`SIGSEGV`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV), либо ваша программа тут же упадет, или вам ***повезет*** и вы получите [`UB`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

В заключении, скажу что либо вы тщательно затираете указатели сами, либо используйте умные указатели дабы избежать проблем *(но при этом скорость выполнения может снизится)*.

P.S. Если указатель лежит на стеке, то вам с ним ничего не нужно делать, т.к. он сам будет освобожден при утилизации стека, а если же он у вас в другой `Node`, то ничего страшного, просто перетрите его `NULL` / `nullptr`.

Comment: Но я правильно понимаю, что указатели освобождаются при достижении конца области видимости? Просто везде говорят, что указатели надо УДАЛЯТЬ. Но я не совсем понимаю. Когда мне указатель (и память, на которую он указывает) мне уже не нужен, мне надо сначала применить delete, чтобы освободить память по адресу, а потом затереть сам указатель через NULL?

Comment: Нужно удалять только в том случае если вы явно выделяли память под указатель, например: `void **pData = new void*[1];` А затирать только в случаях которые я описал в ответе.

Comment: Да, как я уже написал, память под Node я выделяю через new. В таком случае нужно при ненадобности применить оператор delete, а затирать сам указатель через NULL не обязательно?

Comment: Да, не обязательно если вы больше никуда не записывали этот адрес, т.е. он не передавался никуда, к примеру в другую ноду.

Comment: `При вызове оператора delete / delete[], с указателем ничего не происходит...` С точки зрения стандарта языка после `delete` указатель становится невалидным. Доступ к значению такого указателя с точки зрения стандарта языка может запросто  привести к падению программы. См.: [basic.stc.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4).

Comment: @wololo, почитайте ответ.

Comment: `Node * pNode = new Node; delete pNode; cout << pNode;` Это корректный код или нет?

Comment: *`"или вам повезет и вы получите UB`"* -- я бы заменил "повезет" на **не повезет**

Comment: Вообще-то разыменование указателя после освобождения памяти - это UB. А SIGSEGV, мгновенное падение программы или даже дальнейшая нормальная работа - это всё возможные конкретные реализации неопределённого поведения. Ссылку на стандарт вам уже привели в комментариях ранее. Почитайте.

Comment: Я не понимаю смысл комментариев про in, sigsegv, это все описано в ответе